# Do any monospace Unicode fonts include the IBM PUA characters for EBCDIC code page 310?

Tags: mainframe, apl, terminal-emulator, ebcdic, 3270

Do any (preferably, open-source) monospace [Unicode fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) include the IBM Private Use Area (PUA) characters for [EBCDIC code page 310](http://ccsids.net/viewer.html#310)?

For example: [U+F892](http://ccsids.net/viewer.html#1449:F8); EBCDIC code page 310 byte value X'81', GCGID SF630000, "Double Vertical, Bar Graphic". (Look for the SF630000 table cell in row F89_, column _2.)

I'm looking for a font that includes all of the characters that can be displayed on an IBM 3270 terminal.

I'm currently using Noto Sans Mono to present IBM 3270 terminal screen captures in HTML. Noto Sans Mono has good coverage of the APL characters that 3270 screens can display, but lacks the 3270-specific IBM PUA characters. For example, Noto Sans Mono includes the standard U+2551 (BOX DRAWINGS DOUBLE VERTICAL), with the lines close together, but (understandably) not the IBM PUA U+F892, where the lines are as far apart as possible. The glyphs are significantly different.

I'm not necessarily asking for a *single* font that contains, say, every character in Noto Sans Mono plus the IBM PUA characters. A font that includes those IBM PUA characters, that has the same font metrics as Noto Sans Mono, that I can specify via CSS as a "fall back", would work for me for most (if not all) use cases.

For [IBM 3270 screen captures in IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-pa/5.4.0?topic=definitions-zos-connect), I'm using the IBM Plex Mono font. [IBM Plex lacks some of the characters that 3270 terminals can display](https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues/433), but for many screens, that doesn't matter.

For background to this question, see the Talk page section "[Incorrect mapping of EBCDIC code page 310 (APL) to Unicode characters?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Digital_encoding_of_APL_symbols#Incorrect_mapping_of_EBCDIC_code_page_310_%28APL%29_to_Unicode_characters%3F)" of the Wikipedia article "[Digital encoding of APL symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_encoding_of_APL_symbols#Code_page_310)".